# How can I catch SIGSEGV using CoffeeCatch?

Tags: c++, c, java-native-interface

I am trying to use `COFFEE_TRY_JNI` on Android, but it does not seem to catch the signal. I just copied the coffeecatch source files in my project, and had to remove some of [those parts](https://github.com/xroche/coffeecatch/blob/master/coffeecatch.c#L101) because Android now apparently has them. I only removed what was "duplicated" (keeping the system one and removing the one in coffeecatch.c).

I get the following crash:

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x7969a63cb6 in tid 20990 (DefaultDispatch)

From this code, calling `runNative` from Java (well, Kotlin actually):

```c
__attribute__ ((noinline))
static void run() {
    char *test = "blah";
    *(test + 1) = 'n';
}

__attribute__ ((noinline))
static void run_protected(JNIEnv *env) {
    COFFEE_TRY_JNI(env, run());
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_JniApi_00024Companion_runNative(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    run_protected(env);
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: *Am I missing something?*  Almost certainly you are.  JVMs use `SIGSEGV` constantly, trying to get into the middle of that without breaking or missing things is difficult, and any implementation that actually *does* anything is going to be extremely fragile.  I've written code that uses `libunwind` within JNI code to just collect debug data from `SIGSEGV` events and create an actual core file, but I'd never even try to recover from one and keep the JVM running.  IMO there's just waaaay too much that can go wrong or be missed to make such code reliable.  Good luck with your efforts.

Comment: I don't want to recover, I want to collect the debug data for my logs ;-). `COFFEE_TRY_JNI` is supposed to catch the signal, send it as a Java exception, and in my understanding abort() right after.