# How does CoffeeCatch jump back to the COFFEE_CATCH clause?

Tags: c++, c

I recently discovered [CoffeeCatch](https://github.com/xroche/coffeecatch), which I want to use to log the C/C++ native crashes on Android. I haven't managed, but still I am curious about how it works internally.

My understanding is that it basically catches and emitted signal (e.g. SIGSEGV) and allows the user to do something with it; in my case I would like save the stack trace and crash.

It is used like this:

```
COFFEE_TRY_JNI(env, *retcode = call_dangerous_function(env, object));
```

Where `call_dangerous_function()` is a function that could crash and therefore emit a signal.

The macro is defined [here](https://github.com/xroche/coffeecatch/blob/master/coffeejni.h#L117-L124):

```c
#define COFFEE_TRY_JNI(ENV, CODE)       \
  do {                                  \
    COFFEE_TRY() {                      \
      CODE;                             \
    } COFFEE_CATCH() {                  \
      coffeecatch_throw_exception(ENV); \
    } COFFEE_END();                     \
  } while(0)
```

Which [resolves to](https://github.com/xroche/coffeecatch/blob/master/coffeecatch.h#L215-L220) something like this:

```c
  do {                                  
      if (coffeecatch_inside() || 
      (coffeecatch_setup() == 0 
       && sigsetjmp(*coffeecatch_get_ctx(), 1) == 0)) {                      \
      call_dangerous_function(env, object);                             
    } else {                  
      coffeecatch_throw_exception(ENV); 
    } coffeecatch_cleanup();                     
  } while(0)
```

Here, my understanding is that `sigsetjmp(*coffeecatch_get_ctx(), 1) == 0)` somehow sets a pointer to the current "context", which I guess is something like the execution state of this thread at this moment.

So somehow, later, [siglongjmp(t->ctx, code);](https://github.com/xroche/coffeecatch/blob/master/coffeecatch.c#L498) will be called (after the environment has been somehow prepared for it) to jump back here.

What's not clear to me is if we then jump at the `if` statement (and evaluate the statement again), or somehow end up into the `else` statement for some reason.

My expectation is that `siglongjmp` now results in going into the `else` statement (where in my case a Java exception could be thrown). But:

- First, that's not what I see ([my program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72600920/how-can-i-catch-sigsegv-using-coffeecatch) emits the SIGSEGV signal right after `siglongjmp` is called without ever reaching the `else` statement).
- Second, I don't get where `siglongjmp` should actually jump. If it goes to the `if` statement again and evaluates the condition again, it will evaluate to `true` again and that's a loop. How would it go to `else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`siglongjmp` jumps back to where `sigsetjmp` was called, and makes it look like `sigsetjmp` returned the value that `siglongjmp` was passed.  So in this case, if `siglongjmp` is called with a non-zero value, then it will jump back to the `sigsetjmp(*coffeecatch_get_ctx(), 1) == 0` condition, which will evaluate to `false` and thus the `if` will not be satisfied and the `else` block will execute.

It's very unlikely you can meaningfully recover from a SIGSEGV however.  By the time a SIGSEGV happens your program has wandered so far off into undefined behavior that it is impossible to reason about its current state.  There is a high chance that data has been corrupted and/or your call stack has been destroyed.  The only meaningful action is to terminate the process.

---

Note: Using `(sig)?setjmp`/`(sig)?longjmp` in C++ is a very bad idea.  They do not execute object destructors, and thus can easily leak memory and/or violate class invariants.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! One small precision: by "meaningfully recovering", do you also include my scenario where I "just" would like to get the stack trace, send it as a Java exception over JNI, and terminate? That's kind of what CoffeeCatch was written for, right? Or is it specially for SIGSEGV, in which case I can still hope to use it for other signals and uncaught exceptions maybe?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how JNI invokes native code (if it runs within the JVM process or in a separate sandbox or what).  If it runs within the JVM process, then I wouldn't trust that JVM at all after your native code got a SIGSEGV.  Also it seems like CoffeeCatch is `longjmp`ing out of a signal handler, which means everything beyond that point is limited to the [signal-safe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) functions.  I don't know if that's enough to throw a Java exception or not.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks a lot! I guess I'll just have to try with other signals than SIGSEGV and see if that works better :-). I'll also look more closely into the JNI invocation and those signal-safe functions.